# Guide new users away from Meta

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, new-users, off-topic

There are a lot of blatantly off-topic posts put here on Meta. These are apparently people who somehow got to this site without realizing their questions about things like programming aren't supposed to be here.

I think we should have something like the [Ask Question Wizard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378057/the-ask-question-wizard-is-now-in-testing) on Stack Overflow that new users are forced into that tells them what this site is for and sends them away based on a few choices. For example:

- > I want to ask a question about the software that powers the Stack Exchange Network

  going to the normal asking interface.
- > I want to ask a question about programming

  going to Stack Overflow or a submenu with a list of applicable sites.
- > I have a question that doesn't fit into these categories

  going to the full list of sites.